# Evolution of umbilical cord and reason of its elongation

Tags: human-biology, evolution

To answer a question myself, recently I've read that

> Years and years ago, a long umbilical cord enabled a woman to grasp her baby after birth and run away from predators"

Update:

$Question:$ How umbilical cord is evolved and what's the reason behind it's elongation?

[image]

There is at least one position that supports this claim:

> So why 61 cm? Umbilical cords of whales, porpoises, goats and other
>   mammals are rela- tively shorter than the human cord. Walker and Rye
>   of Cambridge surmised in the British Medical Journal in 1960 that
>   prehistoric humans evolved length for protection. Nature's purpose was
>   to allow the mother to pick up the newborn without disturbing the
>   placenta. The event of breast feeding would then separate the placenta
>   - an event which could attract predators. Having the fetus in tow would allow escape for mother and child.

(title: Silent Risk, auth.:Jason H. Collins). Well, right now I feel confused a bit...

Comment: Of course.. thats a folk tale.. Anyways, you do know what umbilical cord is really for, don't you?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should ask another question - why is this so long?

Comment: +1 for the sense of humor; I haven't seen any question of such comical kind here recently.

Comment: :)... is it malice-exchange or science-exchange? :( could you, guys, please help me in either improving my answer or explaining why it's stupid?

Comment: Sorry, but this is bullshit. Anyone who has been at a birth (or given) will know that women will do a lot of things afterwards, but running is usually none of them.

Comment: @Lili: Better Now?

Comment: :-) better (even more than simple "better") - thank you!

Comment: I do believe that this is not a HW question and has scope to be answered

Comment: I seriously doubt the umbilical cord evolved length for running. Humans are a complex social species and it's unlikely mothers would have to run. They would be protected by the group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The woman running bit is obviously a myth but that is genius.. Other than that the length of the umbilical cord has been found to be highly variable depending on each individual. Characterizing it as just long would therefore not be right. According to Wikipedia,

> The umbilical cord in a full term neonate is usually about 50
>   centimeters (20 in) long and about 2 centimeters (0.75 in) in diameter
>   ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilical_cord)).

Some complications during birth are

> A number of abnormalities can affect the umbilical cord. The cord may
>   be too long or too short. It may connect improperly to the placenta or
>   become knotted or compressed ([reference](http://www.marchofdimes.com/pregnancy/umbilical-cord-abnormalities.aspx)).

Why does it become too long has been associated with these factors.

> Long umbilical cords, defined as total length over 70 cm, have been
>   significantly associated with:
>
> **Maternal factors:**
>
> Systemic diseases. Delivery complications. Increased maternal age.
>
> **Fetal factors:**
>
> Non-reassuring fetal status during labor. Respiratory distress. Vertex
>   presentation Cord entanglement. Fetal anomalies. Male sex. Increased
>   birth weight.
>
> **Placental features:**
>
> Increased placental weight. Right-twisted cords. Hyper-coiled cords.
>   True knots ([reference](http://sonoworld.com/fetus/page.aspx?id=1149)).

In conclusion, length of the umbilical cord has an average as mentioned before and being too long or short can lead to complications during birth. Regarding evolution of the cord, you could [read this discussion](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081022201948AA7cVhN).